# Accessing an odd object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

How would I access the keys and values in the following...

```js
users@email.com{"authenticated":"TRUE","devid":"12334567890"}
```

This will be used for logging in. I am making a http post to a php backend.

I want to check if authenticated == true
I also want to be able to use the devid as well.

I know iterating through is an option but i know users@email.com will obviously be changing for every user.
So how can I access this dynamic object?

Comment: This is not a properly formatted object, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Is this object inside another object? like: `users = {"users@email.com": {"authenticated":"TRUE","devid":"12334567890"}}`

Comment: Nope. That is exactly what is being returned from the server @Adrian

Comment: @MichaelChristopherMartire Oh I see, then this is not an object, further processing is needed to make this as an object but not with those `@` and `.` Answer below might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
var fileName='users@email.com{"authenticated":"TRUE","devid":"12334567890"}';
var str1 = fileName.split('{');
var str2 = str1[1].split('}');
var pos = JSON.parse('{'+str2[0]+'}');
alert(pos.authenticated);
```

pos.authenticated will contain your flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.users = {"users@email.com": {"authenticated":"TRUE","devid":"12334567890"}}
  var id = Object.keys($scope.users);
  console.log(id);
 console.log($scope.users[id[0]].authenticated);
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>
```

Comment: its a server response and adding ':' manually is incorrect. Also the email id before the object may be dynamic hence hardcoding wont be right as you assigned to $scope.name.

Comment: You have only one key in object ?